# Very weird Retrofit response

Tags: android, retrofit2

This is my response body.

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class MatchResponse {
    private Match match;
    private Member member;
}
```

I called the REST API and get a response from the server.

The server log shows that all fields are set correctly, especially 'mId' is 540.

```
MatchResponse(match=Match(mId=540, id1=232, id2=3, date=2020-01-13 00:42:13.0, isAcceptedByUser1=false, isAcceptedByUser2=false, isMade=false), member=Member(mId=232, email=test228@gmail.com, password=$2a$10$hj1rs6vTDYkMf0KlSsTV7.ZG.cW23L0UbS0bXUUZaPqLzXLDCUPki, name=null, phone=null, yearOfBirth=1989, gender=male, jobType=null, jobTitle=null, company=구글 코리아, areaType=null, areaName=강남역, roles=[MemberRole(no=229, roleName=MEMBER)]))
```

However, the client shows the 'mId' in the 'Match' class is 0!!!
The weird thing is all other fields are set correctly.

Below is the log from Android Studio.
Why only one field 'mId' is not set here???
Does anybody help me?

Update: 
Match class

```
public class Match { private int mId; private int id1; private int id2; private Date date; private boolean isAcceptedByUser1; private boolean isAcceptedByUser2; private boolean isMade; public boolean isArranged() { return isAcceptedByUser1 && isAcceptedByUser2; } }
```

[image]

Comment: How does class `Match` look alike??

Comment: public class Match {
    private int mId;
    private int id1;
    private int id2;
    private Date date;
    private boolean isAcceptedByUser1;
    private boolean isAcceptedByUser2;
    private boolean isMade;

    public boolean isArranged() {
        return isAcceptedByUser1 && isAcceptedByUser2;
    }
}

Comment: @MartinZeitler Code lines are broken. I wrote my Match class above.

Answer (score 0):

It was caused because JSON parser changed the name of fields when marshaling. I solved this issue by indicating changed the JSON key with the @SerializedName annotation. Another way is to set the JSON key explicitly on the server-side with the @JSONProperty annotation. Anyway, the thing is to keep the consistency of names between the class(server & client) and the JSON.